# Dimension of $L^1$

Tags: linear-algebra

I was trying to think of applications of the first isomorphism theorem from linear algebra, but I've confused myself with this example. After looking at it a few times, I'm not sure where the issue is.

Let $X=[0,1]$ and $\mathcal{L}([0,1])$ be the space of integrable functions on $X$. Then integration $f\to\tau(f)=\int_Xfd\mu$ is a linear function from $\mathcal{L}(X)$ into $\mathbb{R}$. If $N=\{f\in\mathcal{L}(X):f=0 \ a.e.\}$. Then since $\int_Xfd\mu=0\iff f=0 \ a.e.$, we have $\text{ker}(\tau)=N$ and the first isomorpism theorem gives that $L(X)=\mathcal{L}(X)/N\cong\text{image}(\tau)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, which would imply $\text{dim} \ L(X)\leq 1$, and not infinite dimensional.

Comment: If $f(x)=x-\frac{1}{2}$ then $\int_0^1f(x)\;dx=0$, but $f$ is certainly not zero almost everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$N$ is most definitely not the kernel of the map. Remember that the function can be positive in some parts and negative in others and still have integral equal to $0$, for example the function $x-1/2$.

---

In fact every integrable function $f$ has exactly one translate $g(x)=f(x)+c$ which does have integral $0$ (which is what the first isomorphism theorem would point you towards).

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that the equivalence in your solution is false: $f=0$ a.e. implies $\int_X fd\mu=0$, but the converse is not necessarily true. Thus $N\subset\ker(\tau)$, but is **not** equal to the kernel.